# Disk Utility does not seem to recognize the free space on my Mac

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, ssd

I have recently deleted a large number of files on my Macbook Pro. But Disk Utility doesn't seem to notice, and is preventing me from installing World of Warcraft (because it doesn't think I have enough space). No matter how many files I delete, the "available space" only increases in Finder, but not in Disk Utility (which I assume is what WoW is checking against). Check out the differences:

**43GB available**

[image: 43GB Available]

**Only 21GB Available...**

[image: 21GB Avialble]

**Insufficient Space...**

[image: Insufficient Space]

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you remove a Bootcamp partition using something other than the Bootcamp Utility? Are you using Time Machine? (If so, try turning it off and then back on.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz nailed it. it was time machine. Can you post that as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

The disk space was probably taken up by [local Time Machine snapshots](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4878). They are counted as used disk space in Disk Utility but not in Finder. They were deleted when you turned Time Machine off and back on, but you could also have run `sudo tmutil disablelocal` to disable local snapshots.